# How to fill colors of stacked bar plot depending on colors column of df in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot with the colors I am assigning in the "col" column of the df. I tried to do it using scale_color_identity().

The colors were assigned randomly using the following code, because I have a total of 300 countries and cannot assign colors manually.

```
color <- grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]
colors <- fread("country_color.txt", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
colors[,col := sample(color, nrow(colors))]
```

Where the file country_color.txt only has the names of all the countries of my df.

My df looks like this after doing a left_join with the new color values (*colors*) and the rest of my data (*producer_countries*).

```
Country    year   total_value  col    
USA      1995   100        green
China    1995   120        red
Other    1995   150        brown
USA      2000   188        green
China    2000   177        red
Other    2000   320        brown
```

This is the code for the plot, but it is somehow not using the colors assigned in the df.

```
ggplot(producer_countries, aes(fill=reorder(Country, total_value), y=total_value, x=year)) +     
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity",  color = "black", aes(colour=col))+
  scale_color_identity() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Quantity)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `aes(fill=col)` in the `geom_bar()` call, and then use `scale_fill_identity()` as follows:

```
ggplot(producer_countries, aes(fill=reorder(Country, total_value), y=total_value, x=year)) +     
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity",  color = "black", aes(fill=col))+
  scale_fill_identity() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Quantity")
```